# Create a multilevel index dataframe from existing regular indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a set of data from an Excel spreadsheet and now have a regular DataFrame.

Here is what my original dataframe looks like:

```
Meter Number    Site Name   Size
123             Site A      1
456             Site B      10
```

Now I have to add a monthly energy output value for each meter. This means I need to add 12 rows for every existing row in my dataframe. To keep things simple, 12 rows for every existing row can be the same, but scaled by the size of the array. So, I need my new DataFrame to look something like the table below. I will later have to compare this to measured data from the sites.

Do anyone have a recommendation for how to accomplish this with Pandas?
Here is what the new DataFrame needs to look like.

```
Meter Number    Site Name   Size   Month   Expected Energy
123             Site A      1      Jan     .2
123             Site A      1      Feb     .3
...             ...         ...    ...     ...
123             Site A      1      Dec     .25
456             Site B      10     Jan      2.0
456             Site B      10     Feb      3.0
...             ...         ...    ...      ...
456             Site B      10     Dec      2.5
```

I looked through the Pandas documentation on merging DataFrames as well as the MultiIndex guide, but I wasn't able to figure how to accomplish this task.

The expected value list per month can be stored as a dictionary, list, or numpy array. I am going to manually enter that for now.

```
monthly_values = {'Jan': 0.2, 'Feb': 0.3, ... 'Dec': 0.25}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which could give you the values as you wished.(it's a bit ugly though)

```
meter = pd.DataFrame({'Meter Number': [123,456], 'Site Number': ['A','B'], 'Size' : [1,10]}) # creating dataframe
meter = meter.reindex(meter.index.repeat(12)) # expanding the dataframe as mentioned
meter['Month'] = list(range(1,len(meter)+1)) # generating Month column with numbers

t = len(meter) // 12 
month = list(range(1,13)) # dummy list with month numbers. Enter month names insted of numbers if you required
meter.Month = month*t #assigning month numbers to the Month column
```

I'm creating a dataframe of Monthly_values with random numbers as i do not have the actuals.

```
monthly_values = meter[['Meter Number', 'Month']] # taking required 2 columns
monthly_values['Expected Energy'] = np.random.randint(2, 25, len(monthly_values)) # generating random energy values
final_OP = pd.merge(meter, monthly_values)[['Meter Number', 'Site Number', 'Month', 'Expected Energy']] # merging the required columns
```

You can edit the column `Expected Energy` in `monthly_values` dataframe, with actual values then merge with `meter` dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much msr_003. You don't have to split and then merge the columns though. I upvoted your post, but I don't have enough credit here for it to mater.                                                                                                  `expected_energy = [.2, .3, ..., .35]`                                  
`meter['Expected_Energy'] = expected_energy * t * meter.Size`

Comment: @david stump thank you for educating me. will wait for next typical scenario like this.

Comment: You are most welcome. We are all learning together. You did the heavy lifting with the index, reindexing, and the trick of creating a dummy list of numbers to fill in the spaces for the month column.  I struggled with this for hours yesterday.